# Gmail email received by PHP API not showing embaded image

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am receiving HTML emails with embedded images and the images display as expected in GMail. However in my html  can't found image

following screenshot shows broken image in mail body and in inspect element it is

```
<img src="cid:image002.png@01D1BDB3.A9B852C0" v:shapes="_x0000_i1025" height="1227" width="1168">
```

Content-type : multipart/related.

[image]

Comment: You can try to check this [tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) on how to Embed Images in the Emails. It explains here how to do it by using CID embedded Images(Inline Images) and Inline Embedding(Base64 Encoding). You can also know here the pros and cons of the two. Also, it has a sample code that acts like a guide for the viewers. Check also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461133/can-you-and-how-do-you-embed-images-in-an-email-when-using-the-gmail-api?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: I want to receive images in mail , i am not trying to send mail

Comment: did you find any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Like you state yourself, you are receiving a `multipart/related` mime type, but it looks like you're only looking at the `text/html` part.

A `multipart/related` mime type means there are at least 2 parts (each with it's own mime type), so apart from the `text/html`, there's probably a `image/*` mime type part.

In the case of embedded images, the Gmail API sends it in these different parts. As you can see in your case, the html part has a reference to the embedded image `cid:image002.png@01D1BDB3.A9B852C0`, this is the `Content-ID` value of the `image/*` mime type part.

So you would have to read the `image/*` part to get its value and use it to replace the `cid` in the html.