# Gmail displays both HTML and text and HTML parts of email

Tags: python, gmail, mime-mail

I am sending an email to a gmail account using Python. This is the code I'm using

```
msg = email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'myemail@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'toemail@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'HTML test'
msg_html = email.mime.text.MIMEText('<html><head></head><body><b>This is HTML</b></body></html>', 'html')
msg_txt = email.mime.text.MIMEText('This is text','plain')
msg.attach(msg_html)
msg.attach(msg_txt)
#SNIP SMTP connection code
smtpConn.sendmail('myemail@gmail.com', 'toemail@gmail.com', msg.as_string())
```

When I view this email in gmail both the HTML and text version are shown like this:

**This is HTML**

This is text

It should be either displaying text or html, what causes this behavior.

Comment: look at the content you are mailing... This is an issue about what you are sending, not how gmail is rendering

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The message is being sent as `multipart/mixed` (as [this is the default](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart)) when it needs to be sent as `multipart/alternative`. `mixed` means that each part contains different content and all should be displayed, while `alternative` means that all parts have the same content in different formats and only one should be displayed.

```
msg = email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart("alternative")
```

Additionally, you should put the parts in increasing order of preference, i.e., text before HTML. The [MUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_user_agent) (GMail in this case) will render the last part it knows how to display.

See the [Wikipedia article on MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) for a good introduction to formatting MIME messages.