# How to trigger automation job only when there is data in table

Tags: spotfire

I have made an automation which sends email of a visualization . Now i want to trigger email only when there is data in that visualization . Is it possible to do so if yes and then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way in which this is possible but it's fairly convoluted.

1. Create an Automation job file which has the 'Open analysis from Library' step ([link](https://support.tibco.com/s/article/How-to-trigger-an-Iron-Python-Script-when-loading-an-analysis-as-part-of-a-task-through-Automation-Services-Job))
2. Schedule it however you/your organization usually schedule Spotfire automations. Here's how to schedule it using Windows Task Scheduler: [link](https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-45265)
3. Once you have this set up, create an IronPython script within Spotfire which checks the underlying datatable: [data check](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-read-column-values-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython-scripting)
4. If data exists, send email: [HTML email](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-send-email-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython-scripting)
5. Since you're working with a visualization, you might have to google a bit to modify the code to [export the image](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-export-visualization-image-tibco-spotfire-using-ironpython-scripting) and then [create a MIMEImage object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633109/creating-a-mime-email-template-with-images-to-send-with-python-django) which will then be sent with the email.